# gradle sync is failed with the error "Collection is empty" while Android KMM module integration

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

Integrated the Kotlin Multiplatform Module in the existing android project but facing the error "collection is empty"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: gradle sync is failed with the error "collection is empty"